# Reading TrueType 'cmap' Format 4 Subtable in Swift 3

Tags: c, swift, pointers, character-encoding, truetype

How might one go about writing the following C code in Swift?

```
glyphIndex = *(&idRangeOffset[i] + idRangeOffset[i] / 2 + (c - startCode[i]))
```

I'm attempting to read a Format 4 TrueType character mapping table using a simple little binary data reader. All is well and good until pointer manipulation is involved, as I can barely make heads or tails of pointers when working in C, let alone ones masquerading around with `Unsafe` prefixes attached to them.

I've tried multiple things, but nothing seems to work quite right. I guess I'm just not exactly sure how to work with pointer "addresses" in Swift.

For example, here's a more complete idea of where I am:

```
// The following variables are all [UInt16]:
// - startCodes
// - endCodes
// - idDeltas
// - idRangeOffsets

var gids = [Int]()

// Iterate segments, skipping the last character code (0xFFFF)
for i in 0 ..< segCount - 1 {

    let start = startCodes[i]
    let end = endCodes[i]
    let delta = idDeltas[i]
    let rangeOffset = idRangeOffsets[i]
    let charRange = start ..< (end + 1)

    if rangeOffset == 0 {
        gids.append(contentsOf: charRange.map { charCode in
            return (charCode + delta) & 0xFFFF
        })
    }
    else {
        for charCode in charRange {
            // ???
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above, you'll notice `???`. This is where I retrieve the glyph index using the strange C-pointer-address-pointer-huh trick mentioned above. The problem is, I just can't figure it out. Replacing the variables I actually understand, here's what I've got:

```
for charCode in charRange {
        Not too sure about this   Actual value of idRangeOffset[i]
                 |                          |
                 v                          v
    glyphIndex = *(&idRangeOffset[i] + rangeOffset / 2 + (charCode - start))
                   ^
                   |
                Or this
}
```

Are there any Swift 3 pointer gurus out there that can lead me on the path to enlightenment? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For code where you create `glyphIndex` the portion inside the outer brackets creates a pointer. The `*` preceding those brackets then gets the data *pointed to* by that pointer

Comment: The first bit inside the outer brackets, `&idRangeOffset[i]` takes the address of the value in `idRangeOffset[i]`. In C, this is a pointer, i.e. a variable that holds an address of another object. The second part, `+ rangeOffset / 2 + (charCode - start)`, then adds some more values to the *address* so that it now points to somewhere else.

Comment: How this should be correctly represented in swift I have no idea I'm afraid

Comment: @Toby So, for example, let's say `int idRangeOffset[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50}`, would the "address" in `idRangeOffset[2]` literally be the pointer's address (as opposed to the index `2` into the array)? If so, what exactly is the "address?" Are we talking about the offset within the binary data, or what? I apologize for all the questions, pointers just mess my head up.

Comment: Ben, `idRangeOffset[2]` would not result in a n address, but `&idRangeOffset[2]` would do. It would give the address (location in memory) of the second item in that array.

Comment: For a contrived example, say the array `char idRangeOffset[5]` is stored in contiguously memory starting at location 0x3F76, then `char *p = &idRangeOffset[0]` would result in `p` holding the value 0x3F76. Similarly `char *q = &idRangeOffset[2]` would result in `q` holding the value 0x3F78 (assuming 8 bit chars). This would be the same thing as doing `char *q = &idRangeOffset[0] + 2`.

Comment: To add to the confusion, `char *q = idRangeOffset + 2` would also be 0x3F78, assuming the same starting address of 0x3F76.  Now, if we had an array of shorts, i.e. 16-bit integers, instead of characters (`short idRangeOffset[5]`), then `short * q1 = idRangeOffset + 2` would be 0x3F7A, same as `&idRangeOffset[2]` and `&idRangeOffset[0] + 2`.  A word of caution: it might be useful to run through a few C pointer tutorials before trying to translate code like this into Swift.

Answer (score 1):

If I translate your pseudo C code word by word into Swift, it would be something like this:

```
//"May not work" example, do no use this
glyphIndex = withUnsafePointer(to: &idRangeOffset[i]) {idRangeOffsetPointer in
//In some cases `idRangeOffsetPointer` can work as `&idRangeOffset[i]` in C...
    (idRangeOffsetPointer + Int(rangeOffset) / 2 + Int(charCode - start)).pointee
    //To make pointer operation in Swift, all integers need to be `Int`,
    //And to match the C-rule of integer operation, you need to cast each portion to `Int` before adding operation
    //The equivalent to C's dereferencing operator `*` in Swift is `pointee` property
}
```

But this may not work as expected because of the **copy-in/copy-out semantics** of Swift's inout parameter. Swift may create a temporal region which contains the single element `idRangeOffset[i]`, and pass the address of it to `idRangeOffsetPointer`, so the result of the pointer operation may be pointing somewhere near the temporal region, which is completely useless.

If you want to get a meaningful result from the pointer operation, you may need to work in a context where all elements of the array are guaranteed to be placed in a contiguous region.

And also you should need to know that the C-statement:

```
glyphIndex = *(&idRangeOffset[i] + idRangeOffset[i] / 2 + (c - startCode[i]))
```

is based on the fact, that whole `idRangeOffset` and `glyphIdArray` are placed in a contiguous region without any gaps or paddings. (I assume you know well about Format 4.)

So, if your `idRangeOffset` contains only `segCount` elements, the following code would not work.

```
//"Should work" in a certain condition
glyphIndex = idRangeOffset.withUnsafeBufferPointer{idRangeOffsetBufferPointer in
    let idRangeOffsetPointer = idRangeOffsetBufferPointer.baseAddress! + i
    //`idRangeOffsetPointer` is equivalent to `&idRangeOffset[i]` in C inside this closure
    return (idRangeOffsetPointer + Int(rangeOffset) / 2 + Int(charCode - start)).pointee
}
```

But with considering the pointer and array semantics in C, the code above is equivalent to this:

```
glyphIndex = idRangeOffset[i + Int(rangeOffset) / 2 + Int(charCode - start)]

//`*(&arr[i] + n)` is equivalent to `arr[i + n]` in C
```

I repeat, **the Array `idRangeOffset` needs to contain whole content of idRangeOffset and glyphIdArray**.

Comment: Okay, I feel like we're getting closer. Before I posted my question, I tried the `withUnsafeBufferPointer` technique, but to no avail. However, you're telling me that I need to include the contents of `glyphIndexArray` at the end of the `idRangeOffset` contents, so it's one long contiguous array? Does this allow the underlying storage to be stored as a cohesive unit of memory on the heap or something? Forgive me for my ignorance; my Swift <=> C game isn't as sharp as I'd like it to be.

Comment: _it's one long contiguous array?_ True. It may contain some hundreds of thousands of elements. _Does this allow the underlying storage to be stored as a cohesive unit of memory on the heap or something?_ Not true in strict meaning, but you can think it true when **accessing through subscript** or **inside the closure of `withUnsafeBufferPointer`**. As OmniProg's answer is suggesting, in binary data format, the meaning of the contents may depend on their absolute locations or offsets. Hope my answer would help you get exactly there.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what @OOPer said, I would suggest reading the whole cmap or subtables of interest into memory and working with them in Swift using  documentation as a guide; see, for example, https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM06/Chap6cmap.html.  You could also use a C implementation as a reference, but that is not a good path unless you are an experienced C programmer: there are too many subtleties in C that can and will bite you.  In C it's really convenient to work with a cmap in terms of pointers and offsets.  Because Swift is not that pointer-friendly, it's better to just use offsets into a table.  You will likely run into problems interpreting different parts of the map as values of different types, but at least you won't have to deal with pointer magic.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I actually am trying to load it all into memory to work with stuff the "Swift" way, and for most other tables (including the other Format subtables), that's what I've been doing. This stupid C pointer thing is the only thing holding me back right now. Other than the Format 4 parsing, I'm really feeling good about stuff. All the tables I've got are nice value types, I'm `lazy`-loading data where I can, and it's really pretty sweet. I totally agree with you; I try to steer clear of too much C, as you said it best: there are so many subtleties!